# Git branches content

Tags: git, git-branch

When I create a new branch I see the same content just as it's in 'master'.

How do I separate the content so that whatever content is in the branch is only in the branch and whatever in master, stays in the master?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just create a new repository? The branch mechanism is not intended for what you're describing.

Comment: You are SVN user, right? It happens because you make your branch from master.

Comment: Ok so the scenario is like this. I have a library that I developed and I need to do 4 more projects based on that library. Is it better to create ANOTHER repository or something else? What is the common scenario?

Comment: You create your 4 projects. Then import your library as a git submodule. When it happens that you change your library, you commit and push updates. Then update the submodule in your projects.

Answer (score 5):

When you branch, you are already separating contents. You see the same content as in master because you haven't already committed any changes.
Try to change a file and then commit. This new change will remain in your branch and will not be present in your master branch.

[Read this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) about basic branching.